# Verify phone input Jquery?

Tags: jquery, validation, input

I have some input that i want to allow just phone to be entered, no letters no minus and first must character must be plus sign, and also not bigger than 12 characters. That final result must be something like this

**+1234567891**

Here is my code so far

```
<input id="phone"></input>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[ -]/g, ''));
});
```

Here I just don't allow space and minus, i need to add no letters and first must be always +, and no bigeer that 12 characters

Here is working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/9zza5ycc/

Comment: FWIW, it's much nicer on the end-user to merely check for 12 numerals and format it as needed on the back end (strip out dashes, add the plus sign, etc.)

Comment: I know but i need this in front end

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this is the perfect way or not. But i can provide you one solution.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#phone").keydown(function(event) {
            if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) || (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
                    return;
            } else {
                if ((event.keyCode != 107 && !(event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 61))  && (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 ))) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });
        $("#phone").blur(function(event) {
            var phoneNo = $('#phone').val();
            if(phoneNo.charAt(0) != '+' || (phoneNo.split("+").length > 2) || phoneNo.length > 13 || phoneNo.length < 13)
            {
                alert('please enter valid phone number');
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4xupb5uw/

Comment: It does not work, only first must be + not to allow + in other space

Comment: It will check '+' occurrences on blur event. Sorry on each time key press how to check i don't know.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove everything from input that is not number or + character.

```
var o = input.replace(/[^\+\d]+/g, '');
```

then you can test if it's in correct format:

```
if(/^\+[\d]{6,12}$/.test(o)){
  console.log('Starts with '+' and has 6 - 12 digits')
} else {
  console.log('Wrong format')
}
```

This regex will validate your input as:

- starts from '+' character
- followed by 6-12 digits

Comment: Ony first hase to be +, not other

Comment: If you are interested only in checking if input matches your pattern than you need  only my if statement. I is correct. First goes + charactera, then from 1 to 12 digits. That is what you wanted, yes?

Answer (score 0):

From the specs you listed, it sounds like your just looking to validate international phone numbers..

If I'm not mistaken, it's common for people to format international numbers with a couple of spaces after the first 2 digits and after the subsequent next 3 digits so you may want to check for spaces as well.

```
function validTel(phone) {
    var arg = /^\+(?:[0-9]\x20?){6,14}[0-9]$/;

    if (arg.test(phone)) {
        // passed
    } else {
        // failed
    }
}
```

---

`^` sets us at the beginning of the string. `\+` specifies that the first character be a plus. `(?:` group.. `[0-9]` digits, `\x20` and a space `?` zero or once. `)` end group.  `{6,12}` repeat between 6 and 12 times, `[0-9]` matching digits. `$` end query.

This should ensure that the string begins with the <kbd>+</kbd> symbol, contains only digits (potentially separated with a single space), and is 6 to 12 characters long.